# How to get the content of a node with Devel Path?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am quite new to Drupal an would like to get the Data of a Node. With the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module I read out the Path to the information I like get with PHP.

```
$var->location['postal_code']
```

How can I access this path? I would like to get this info an pass to Javascript. So I think I have to access this path with PHP and then use `drupal_add_js` to pass it to JS. But I don`t even know where to put the PHP code.

Any suggestion?

Comment: sorry, Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to expose a piece of data to JavaScript, you can use `drupal_add_js()` to add a "setting". Here is the example from api.drupal.org:

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');
```

(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x)

That then becomes available in the frontend in the Javascript variable: `Drupal.settings.myModule.key`.

Now, the question is WHERE do you put that call to `drupal_add_js`? That depends on exactly what data you want to expose, and when you want to expose it, but in general you would create a custom module and implement a Drupal hook that runs `drupal_add_js` at a specific point in the Drupal pageload life cycle.

If, as it sounds from your question, you want to add node information to a node's "view" page (ie: on the /node/1 path), one option is to implement `hook_node_view()` in a module called `mymodule` like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  // If the node contains the field we want, add it to a JS setting.
  if (!empty($node->location['postal_code'])) {
    drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('postal_code' => $node->location['postal_code'])), 'setting');
  }
}
```

Here is the documentation for that hook: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x

That's just one way to do it. There are lots of other hooks where this could be done, again: depending on when and where you want it to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to get my data in template.php with 
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 $node = $variables['node'];
 $x = $variables['location']['postal_code'];
}
but in JS a get a ReferenceError that myvar is not defined.
If I am building a custom module, is it possible that its only active for special content types?
My site has a clean URL, no /node/.  On that site, I have the actual node content from which I get the postal code. and a view block, where I filter the content with postal_code. there is another block with js content, where the postal_code is used